# Why can I use route task only in San Diego and not all over the world?

Tags: arcgis-server, java, routing

I built an application in Java with ArcGIS SDK that uses route task. The only route task I've found is San Diego's with this URL: `http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/NetworkAnalysis/SanDiego/NAServer/Route`

```
RouteTask routeTask = new RouteTask(~the_above_url~);
routeTask.loadAsync();
```

Is there another URL? Is there a way to perform route tasks in other places in the world?

[image: Only in the red area the task works]

Comment: python uses https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/services;World/Utilities;{0};{1}".format(username, password) if you have a vaild subscription

Comment: The answer to your "why" is because the service only has data for San Diego. It's not a world-wide service. Its local. Its there for testing, thus there is no cost. Answers have been provided that point to the WORLD network services which consume credits.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL you want is https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World/solve

Full instructions on using ESRI routing services are here: https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/get-directions-and-route/

But as @mapperz mentioned there is a cost. The table at the bottom of this page gives the rates: https://developers.arcgis.com/features/directions/